# How to do a top grouping by road and direction and severity without specifying the road

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of roughly 8000 segments of highway that I have made a calculated metric called LOTTR_AMP for. Each segment of highway is labeled as a TMC which denotes location and direction on the highways. I am trying to figure out how to make a grouping where the highest 10 LOTTR values are grouped by both road and direction without specifying the road. I can do it on a per road basis but doing that for the entire state would be impossible. I would have to key in each individual road one by one to get the results.

This is the best code I could make up for this that only does one road at a time:

```
select lottr_AMP, TMC_CODE, road, direction 
from [dbo].[TMCF6] 
where road = 'I-40' 
order by road, direction, lottr_amp desc
```

Here is the table I am pulling from:

[image]

Comment: Please add full table schemas, sample data, and desired results. Also post any code you have so far and explain what changes you require. This is too vague as currently written.

Comment: Add more details about what is the schema of your database?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
;with a as (
select lottr_AMP, TMC_CODE, road, direction
, rnk = row_number() over (partition by road, direction order by lottr_amp  desc)
from [dbo].[TMCF6]
)
select lottr_AMP, TMC_CODE, road, direction, rnk
from a
where rnk <=10
order by road, direction, rnk desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `dense_rank` like below:

```
;with cte as
(
    select lottr_AMP, TMC_CODE, road, direction, dense_rank() over (partition by road, direction order by lottr_AMP desc) as rn
    from [dbo].[TMCF6] 
)
select *
from cte where rn <= 10
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. I have never used dense_rank before so I need to research on how this function operates.

Comment: @benfardot [this](https://codingsight.com/similarities-and-differences-among-rank-dense_rank-and-row_number-functions/#:~:text=Unlike%20the%20RANK%20and%20DENSE_RANK,as%20their%20RANK%20and%20DENSE_RANK.) would be a good place to learn the differences among various ranking functions.